# Checkride and Basicmed

Tags: faa-regulations, checkride, basicmed

I am about to take my check ride, but my FAA 3<sup>rd</sup> class medical is still pending. I have not been denied, just jumping through some FAA hoops.

I have taken and completed the online course for basic med. Am I OK to take my check ride?

The only thing basic med asked is if I had applied for a FAA physical before... which I have.

I haven’t found much on this particular problem, so I’m looking for help. Any input is appreciated!

Comment: How did you get the required solo hours without sorting out your medical situation?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Can you give us a little more information? Which checkride are you doing (private, commercial etc.)? Have you ever held a 3rd class medical before? And note that [the requirements for BasicMed](https://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/airmen_certification/basic_med/) include previously *holding* - not just applying for - a medical and completing a physical exam; doing the online course by itself isn't enough.

Comment: [Closely related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/49885/62) and a possible duplicate (?), depending on the details of the OP's situation

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately if you have never held a valid medical certificate since July 14, 2006, the answer is no.  One of the eligibility requirements for BasicMed is that you must have held a medical certificate after  that date.

[§61.89(d)](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/retrieveECFR?gp&n=14y2.0.1.1.2&r=PART#se14.2.61_189) states

> The holder of a student pilot certificate may act as pilot in command
> of an aircraft without holding a medical certificate issued under part
> 67 of this chapter provided the student pilot holds a valid U.S.
> driver’s license, meets the requirements of §61.23(c)(3), and the
> operation is conducted consistent with the requirements of paragraphs
> (a) and (b) of this section and the conditions of §61.113(i). Where
> the requirements of paragraphs (a) and (b) of this section conflict
> with §61.113(i), a student pilot must comply with paragraphs (a) and
> (b) of this section.

§61.113(i) required that pilot hold a valid U.S. driver’s license, meet the requirements of §61.23(c)(3), and complies with this section and the conditions listed in §61.23(c)(3).

But §61.23(c)(3)(B) states that a person operating an a/c without a medical certificate under §61.113(i) must have:

> At any point after July 14, 2006, have held a medical certificate
> issued under part 67 of this chapter.

As such you will have to acquire a medical in this case before you can take the checkride.